# Creating Login system from a text file with multiple logins

Tags: python, authentication

I am trying to make a login/registration system in which has to be validated by a text file. I have put my code below, I can make it so that it records the first username and password but have attempted with a awful while loop to attempt to cycle through the text file to match the other credentials, would appreciate any help.

```
def Register():
FirstName = input()
Surname = input()
DateOfBirth = input()
Letter1 = FirstName[0]
Letter123 = Surname[0] + Surname[1] + Surname[2]
Number1 = DateOfBirth[-1] + DateOfBirth[-2]
Username = (Letter1 + Letter123 + Number1)
Password = input()

file = open("Credentials.txt", "a")
file.write(Username)
file.write(" ")
file.write(Password)
file.write(" ")

print("Your details have now been saved")

def Login():
Username = input()
Password = input()
while line in open("Credentials.txt","r").readlines():
  login_info = line.split()
  while Username == login_info[0] and Password == login_info[1]:
    if true:
        print ("Correct Login")
    elif Username == login_info[0+1] and Password == login_info[1+1]:
        print("Correct Login")
    else:
        print ("Invalid Login")
```

Comment: It looks like a very open-ended question, without any clear answer that can be given. Are you just looking for some general advice and good practices or do you need some help solving a particular problem?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this website Introduction to Storing Data in Files(https://www.pythonforthelab.com/blog/introduction-to-storing-data-in-files/#id4)?